# MongoDB aggregation result difference

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I'm trying to compose a query to find all documents in a collection with the 'date' < current date, flag = true, sort by date (descending) and limit the result to (e.g.) 10 documents, then select all the **remaining** documents (satisfying the date and flag conditions) in the collection for an update to be performed. SQL equivalent would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE < SYSDATE
AND FLAG = TRUE
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE < SYSDATE
AND FLAG = TRUE
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 10
```

So far I have:

```
db.scratch.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { flag: true, date: { $lt: new Date() } } },
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    { $limit: 10 }
  ]
)
```

Is it possible to make the subtraction in the DB, or the only option I have is to process the results of two queries on the client side?

Comment: How is that not simply `.find({ "date": { "$gt": new Date() }, "flag": false }).sort({ "date": -1 }).limit(10)`? `MINUS` is an "exclusion", therefore on the "same collection/table" it means simply "reverse the logical conditions". So it's pretty bad SQL, making a simple statement overcomplicated just for the sake of it. Don't persist bad code, but correct it instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, I didn't specify the requirement correctly. Please see the updated description and query. Basically, I want to get all the docs satisfying the date and flag conditions except the newest top 10.

Comment: Then do `.skip(10)` instead of `limit(10)`. And "don't reverse" the operators. Inverse of Limit is Skip to put it simply. MINUS has no place here, in MongoDB nor in the original query which can also be simplified.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, that's what I've been looking for! :) Please put it as an answer for me to accept it, if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually just a simple query as `MINUS` merely does an "exclusion" and all you are really saying boils down to *"exclude the first 10 results by these criteria"*.

```
db.scratch.find({ "date": { "$lt": new Date() }, "flag": true })
  .sort({ "date": -1 }).skip(10);
```

So *"limit the first 10 and then exclude those results from the overall"* is basically reduced to SKIP, on the same criteria.